# zip 2 lists of dictionaries into 1

Tags: python, list, dictionary, zip

I have a first list like so

```
[{"name":"jon", "age":10}, {"name":"mary", "age":12}]
```

And a second list like so

```
[{"city":"nyc"}, {"city":"la"}]
```

And would like to combine them into a single list of dicts. They are assumed to be of same length too.

```
[{"name":"jon", "age":10, "city":"nyc"}, {"name":"mary", "age":12, "city":"la"}]
```

thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `list comprehension`:

```
>>> lis1 = [{"name":"jon", "age":10}, {"name":"mary", "age":12}]
>>> lis2 = [{"city":"nyc"}, {"city":"la"}]
>>> [dict(x, **y) for x, y in zip(lis1, lis2)]
[{'city': 'nyc', 'age': 10, 'name': 'jon'}, {'city': 'la', 'age': 12, 'name': 'mary'}]
```

As [Guido dislikes](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2010-April/099459.html) `dict(x, **y)`, another option is:

```
>>> [dict(x.items() + y.items()) for x, y in zip(lis1, lis2)]
[{'city': 'nyc', 'age': 10, 'name': 'jon'}, {'city': 'la', 'age': 12, 'name': 'mary'}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Also simply:

```
for i in xrange(len(x)):
    x[i].update(y[i])
```

Answer (score 2):

Three new ways, all direct variants:

```
from collections import ChainMap

first  = [{"name":"jon", "age":10}, {"name":"mary", "age":12}]
second = [{"city":"nyc"}, {"city":"la"}]
```

Firstly:

```
map(ChainMap, first, second)
#>>> <map object at 0x7fee1c53ddd0>
```

Note that this **doesn't** copy the objects. If you need it in an actual list:

```
[ChainMap(f, s) for f, s, in zip(first, second)]
#>>> [ChainMap({'name': 'jon', 'age': 10}, {'city': 'nyc'}), ChainMap({'name': 'mary', 'age': 12}, {'city': 'la'})]
```

If you need it copied:

```
[dict(ChainMap(f, s)) for f, s, in zip(first, second)]
#>>> [{'name': 'jon', 'age': 10, 'city': 'nyc'}, {'name': 'mary', 'age': 12, 'city': 'la'}]
```

Honestly this seems nicer to me than `dict(first.items() + second.items())` and it's also quite stable.